# Issue with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am working on date format with `SimpleDateFormat`. But when I format my date in provide format, year value increment by 1.The condition happen with that value. Why this happen?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");
System.out.println("dob - "+date); // Java date
System.out.println("formatted date - "+sdf.format(date));
```

Output as follows :

```
dob - Sun Dec 28 00:00:00 IST 1975
formatted date - 28-12-1976
```

Year value increment by 1. Why this happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

capital Y means week year,you should use `yyyy` in place of `YYYY`

change `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY");` to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");`
as `y` means year while 'Y' means week Year.

Below are supported codes to be used in SimpleDateFormat.

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation    Examples
G   Era designator  Text    AD
y   Year    Year    1996; 96
Y   Week year   Year    2009; 09
M   Month in year   Month   July; Jul; 07
w   Week in year    Number  27
W   Week in month   Number  2
D   Day in year Number  189
d   Day in month    Number  10
F   Day of week in month    Number  2
E   Day name in week    Text    Tuesday; Tue
u   Day number of week (1 = Monday, ..., 7 = Sunday)    Number  1
a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
H   Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0
k   Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)    Number  0
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)    Number  12
m   Minute in hour  Number  30
s   Second in minute    Number  55
S   Millisecond Number  978
z   Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
Z   Time zone   RFC 822 time zone   -0800
X   Time zone   ISO 8601 time zone  -08; -0800; -08:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "yyyy" instead of "YYYY".

See for more info:
[SimpleDateFormat producing wrong date time when parsing "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916958/simpledateformat-producing-wrong-date-time-when-parsing-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmm)

- Y means "Week year"
- y means "Calendar year"

Comment: @Shirish was faster :-)